# Ansible "The task includes an option with an undefined variable" when using set fact across hosts

Tags: ansible

Getting undefined variable, even though debug is printing it out when using vars across hosts.

Inventory:

```
[host-group1]
10.X.Y.Z node_name=host1

[host-group2]
10.A.B.C node_name=host2

[all:vars]
host1_ip="10.X.Y.Z"
```

Host1:

```
- name: Get the token
  shell: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
  register: tmp_kubeadm_join_token

- name: Store the token
  set_fact:
    kubeadm_join_token: "{{ tmp_kubeadm_join_token.stdout  }}"
```

Host2:

```
- debug: var=hostvars['{{ host1_ip }}']['kubeadm_join_token']
  run_once: true

- name: Join the cluster
  shell: "{{ hostvars['{{ host1_ip }}']['kubeadm_join_token'] }} --control-plane"
```

Result:

```
ok: [10.A.B.C] => {
    "hostvars['10.X.Y.Z']['kubeadm_join_token']": "kubeadm join kube-lb:6443 --token XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
fatal: [10.A.B.C]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['{{ host1_ip }}']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/myuser/k8s/path/to/main.yml': line XX, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Join the cluster\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: `hostvars` is a dictionary. A host is missing in the declaration `hostvars[host1_ip]` (I removed the braces and the quotation to fix the syntax). Include a host, e.g. `hostvars[inventory_hostname][host1_ip]` wherever the expression is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this workaround:

```
  shell: "{{ hostvars[item]['kubeadm_join_token'] }} --control-plane"
  with_items: "{{ groups['host-group1'] }}"
```